# Sum of any two elements in a given array

Tags: ruby, arrays

What's a good way to find sum of any two elements in a given array?

I have the following code, but it looks kind of ugly

```
def sum_to_n?(a, n)
  sums = []
  a.each_index do |i|
    b = a.drop(i+1)
    b.each_index do |j|
      sums << a[i] + b[j]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: a method with `method?` name should return a boolean, it's a convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xs = [1, 5, 8, 10]
xs.combination(2).map { |x, y| x + y }
#=> [6, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18]
```

Comment: Magical! Thanks for quick response. ;)

Comment: Or, for the general case `xs.combination(n).map {|v| v.reduce(&:+) }`

Comment: @p11y: yup, only note that `vs.reduce(:+)`

Comment: @tokland nice! Since when is this possible?

Comment: Strange. This seems to be quite inconsistent, e.g. `Enumerable#map` will not accept symbols as arguments.

Comment: I think it's possible from 1.8.7, it's well documented. There is a reason why inject allows it: a catamorphism (folding) is usually a binary operation of two values (the accumulated and the element being processed) so it makes sense to get this operator (method). Anyway, I'd also like to have `[1,2,3].map(:to_s)` :)